# Django не выполняет миграции

Tags: django, django-model

В общем ситуация: `django` не выполняет миграции от слова "совсем" на `models.py`. Ошибок нет, просто ничего не происходит Я уже весь гугл перерыл. Шаги по порядку:

1. Создал проект
2. Создал и применил миграции, что бы не ругался терминал, БД создается
3. Создал суперпользователя
4. Создал в `models.py` класс, создал миграции `makemigrations` и тут `django` миграции не видит. При выполнении `migrate` ничего не происходит.

В IDE проблем тоже нет, пробовал и `VS Code` и `PyCharm` (сначала думал, что какая то специфичная ошибка в IDE винды). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Почему вы не создаете приложение? Где вы создали models.py файл, относительно корневой папки проекта?